# How to add highlighting border on buttonbar Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have buttonbar with a few buttons, here is the code:

```
ButtonBar(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topRight,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          colors: <Color>[
                            Colors.purpleAccent,
                            Colors.pinkAccent,
                          ],
                          stops: const <double>[
                            0.5,
                            0,
                          ],
                        ),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,

                      ),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () =>
                              setColors(Colors.purpleAccent, Colors.pinkAccent),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                            primary: Colors.transparent,
                            shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                          child: Ink())
                  ),
                  ...
)
```

I want to highlight selected button with border, something like this:
[image]

How can I do this with current architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I have try using `ListView.builder()`, not ButtonBar hope its help to you.use **`StatefulWidget`** for below code

declare index and bool variable:

```
bool isPressed = false;
int? buttonIndex;
```

Your Widget:

```
 Center(
    child: ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
          height: 40,
          width: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isPressed && buttonIndex == index
                  ? Colors.primaries[index]
                  : Colors.transparent,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[index],
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isPressed = !isPressed;
                      buttonIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const SizedBox(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Result Screen normal/without button click-> [image]

Result Screen with button click->[image]

Test above code on [**`Dartpad`**](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)